# Determine whether the following series converges absolutely , conditionally or diverges:

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the following series converges absolutely , conditionally or diverges:

(i) $ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{k^2-2}{k^2+6} \ $

(ii) $ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{k^2}{(3k)!} \ $

**Answer:**

(i)

The series is $ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{k^2-2}{k^2+6} \ $

$ a_k=(-1)^n \frac{k^2-2}{k^2+6} \ $

The series is alternating series .

But the term of series does not decrease by its absolute value. So how can we conclude about the convergence of the series.

further taking absolute value, we get

$ \ |a_k|=\frac{k^2-2}{k^2+6} \ $

For absolute convergence,

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} |=1 \ $

so we can say whether converges or not

(ii) The given series is $ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{k^2}{(3k)!} \ $

This is an alternatic series test.

The absolute value of each term decreases from the previous term.

Thus by Alternating series test , the series converges.

But the series does not converges absolutely.

**Help with the part $ \ (i) \ $ question**

Comment: In (1) we have that $a_n$ does NOT converge to zero.

Comment: Remember that if $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k\neq 0$ then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ does not converge, and vice versa if $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ does converge then $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k=0$

Comment: So the series diverges in $ \ (i) \ $

Comment: Am I correct about the series in part $ \ (ii) \ $ ?

Comment: Why, and how, did you determine the series (ii) does not converge absolutely?

Comment: It was  mymistake . As $ |\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} |=\frac{1}{(3k+1)(3k+2)(3k+3)} \to 0 \ $